# sagas - tracking and processing parallel tasks

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, redux, react-redux, redux-saga

docs indicate that in order to run parallel tasks, we do something like this

`const [ a, b, c, ] = yield [ forkA, forkB, forkC ]`

what strategies would you suggest for handling the status of each of these tasks?

for example:

a/c are successful, do X action
b is not successful, do y action

I thought about utilizing actionChannels along the lines of

`const tasksStarted = yield actionChannel(start_task);
const tasksCompleted = yield actionChannel(end_task);`

Each completed task can then be placed in their corresponding bucket (X/Y)

However, I'm not sure if this is over-engineered and wanted a sanity check if anyone else has solved similar issues.

To give a sense of scale, the upper bound of this array of tasks can be up to 20.

I also posted this in Redux-Saga issues, but since the community here is great, I thought it'd be worth it in try both *ahem* channels.

Comment: does your state update in any way when a task completes? just knowing in your state seems the easiest, most obvious way

Comment: since these are parallel, nonblocking forks, I can't necessarily respond to them on the line after with yield put({}). I could yield [ callA, callB ], but the entire program would be blocked until they all complete (which is not desirable)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you use sagas for execution of some asynchronous operations which shall exchange data on the status. The simplest option in the current situation use of the fork function () instead of automatic construction which captures all redux actions. See https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/advanced/ForkModel.html for general info about forking model.

If it is required not just to organize a set of the expecting flows, but also to make in them branching depending on a mutual status, it is possible to use a trick with closing and the "frozen" promise.

```
function generateTrigger() {
  let raiseSuccess = null, raiseFail = null;
  let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    raiseSuccess = resolve;
    raiseFail = reject;
  })
  return {
    raiseSuccess,
    raiseFail,
    promise
  }
}

let trigger = generateTrigger();

function* task1() {
  while(true) {
    // Some code
    if (isSuccess) {
      trigger.raiseSuccess();
      trigger = generateTrigger();
    } else {
      trigger.raiseFail();
      trigger = generateTrigger();
    }
    // Some code
  }
}

function* task2() {
  while(true) {
    // Some code
    try {
      yield call(() => trigger.promise);
      // If task1 done with success
    } catch (e) {
      // If task1 done with fail
    }
    // Some code
  }
}

function* main() {
  try {
    yield fork(task1)
    yield fork(task2)
  } catch (e) {
  }
}
```